# Testing Spring boot application with Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, cucumber

My requirement is to Test my Spring boot application using BDD. I chose cucumber for this purpose. While looking for any tutorial that would help me do this, i came across many and i end up confusing myself. Below are my requirements

1. I want to be able to test my application while building it using `mvn test` from command line
2. I want do previous step in my build server as well.

My expectation was if I simply run `mvn test` then maven should fireup my application and will execute my features step by step but in actually it doesn't start my application, instead it run the test, which expects my application to be running and it tries to consume those services. Below is my Cucumber Test class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue="com.api.resources.steps",
        format = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun.txt"
        }
)
public class ApiTests {
}
```

My FeatureStep class

```
@TestConfigs
public class FacebookAuthentication{
    public static final String HOST="http://localhost:8080";
    @Given("^User requests authentication by providing \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\" obtained from facebook$")
    public void userRequestsAuthenticationByProvidingAndObtainedFromFacebook(String arg0, String arg1) throws Throwable {
        String token = "token";
        String id = "id";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("token",token);
        map.put("id",id");
        String response = HttpUtilForTests.sendPostRequest(HOST+"/auth/facebook", map, "");
    }

    @When("^Facebook returns User details with \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void facebookReturnsUserDetailsWithAnd(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {

    }

    @Then("^User should be authorized in pixyfi application and return User info with UserToken$")
    public void userShouldBeAuthorizedInPixyfiApplicationAndReturnUserInfoWithUserToken() throws Throwable {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

My Test Config

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = GlobalTestonfig.class)
public @interface TestConfigs {

}

@Configuration
@Import(MyApplication.class)
class GlobalTestonfig {

}
```

With above settings `mvn test` start my tests but consuming service at http://localhost:8080 fails as the service itself is not started. 
could you please help me out here with where exactly i'm mistaking?

Comment: You need to start the service before the tests are executed. You can add some instructions to do this on a @BeforeClass method on the ApiTests class that will start the service or you might be able to use some maven configuration to start/stop the service before the tests are executed.

Comment: i don't want to run my application separately. There must be something which does this, which is why it is considered as integration test and not unit test

Comment: If you want the application to be started before the test, you will have to start it somehow. Either start it manually yourself when testing on your local machine, or configure you pipeline to start it before running your tests.